# linking activeX control's command button to a module

Tags: excel, vba, module, commandbutton

okay so here is my question. Is it possible to call a module from an activeX Control command button on the Excel sheet?

Here is the scenario: i have a sheet called Menu. On Menu, there is 10 activeX Control command buttons.I need the command button to call or linked it to a module. I haven't the slightest idea on how this could be achieved. Is it even possible? If so, how do i go about doing it? if not is there an alternative?

[image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: Link to a **Module** or a **Sub** within a Module??

Comment: link to a sub within a module @Gary'sStudent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Open the VB Editor (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>)
2. Under 'Microsoft Excel Objects' in the Project Explorer window, right click the sheet that the buttons appear on and select 'View Code'

[image: View Code]

3. In the upper left-hand drop down, select the appropriate command button

[image: Command Button]

4. This will add the following code into the appropriate worksheet module

   ```
   Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
   'Your on click actions go here
   End Sub
   ```

Which means now we can do actions (call our subroutine, for example)

```
    Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
        Call MyMacro
    End Sub
```

Now, `MyMacro` can be present either in the worksheet level code that the `Click` event is in, or it can exist as a `Public Sub` somewhere in a module.

### Update

To show a userform use the name of the userform with the `Show` method.  The default name is `UserForm1` (or `UserForm2` or `UserForm3` etc. depending on how many you add).

If you want to show this userform on click you could use this code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
        UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks!  I have 1 question if you could answer me it would be great. is it possible to link the "submit" button in the picture above to a userform? is it the same as calling a subroutine? @JoshuaRoss

Comment: If you want to show a userform you can use the `UserForm.Show` method, I will update my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple.  When you add an active control to an excel sheet, you can then open the module for the worksheet and then add code for it there.

Make sure you add an activeX button NOT a excel button as these are different things.

You will need the "developer tab" on the ribbon showing (google "add developer tab to excel ribbon") to allow you to insert controls and access the VBA editor.

You can right click  on the control button and choose "view code" - which will create the click event.  You can add code to call any existing macro.  eg `Call MyMacro1`

Note that in the module editor you can use the combo boxes at the top to select the control name and the type of event you want to add to create the event handler declaration code.  So you can add the code for all 10 buttons from here.

Harvey